# Connecting Button to Navigational View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, button, interface

Here is the design of an account tab in iOS application.
[image]

I want to connect the logOut button with Sign In interface.
And connect the Done button in edit interface with Account interface.

But when I connect them either using show or model segeue, here's what happens!
[image]

Is there anyway to connect them through coding and not getting this result?

Could you help me please, what I have to do to make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try out this if it's the Root View Controller

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Or if it's not then

```
// pops to the 3rd controller in the stack, because indexing starts with 0
navigationController!.popToViewController(navigationController!.viewControllers[2], animated: false)
```